# variogramST in R

Tags: r, variogram

I've been following the tutorial in [this](http://www.r-bloggers.com/spatio-temporal-kriging-in-r/) site to compute the spatio-temporal variogram in R. The result from variogramST is the object called var, and it contains several NAs for np, dist, and gamma, but the remaining columns have values (id, timelag, spacelag, and avgDist). Can you explain to me why these NAs appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the author of the tutorial in the link and it turns out that variogramST combines measurements in each hour (in case tunit = "hours"), and the NAs appear in case the corresponding space-time intervals are without observation.